# DateTimeField. Удалить ссылки "Сегодня" и "Сейчас"

Tags: django, django-admin

В админке есть виджет:

[image: DateTime]

Как удалить ссылки "Сегодня" и "Сейчас" и палки рядом с ними?

Comment: Создать свой собственный виджет, наверное. А зачем удалять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам в потроха админки:

> Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\admin\DateTimeShortcuts.js

и там внести изменения:

```
    //shortcuts_span.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u00A0'));
    //shortcuts_span.appendChild(now_link);
    //shortcuts_span.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u00A0|\u00A0'));
    shortcuts_span.appendChild(clock_link);
```

и чуть ниже

```
    //shortcuts_span.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u00A0'));
    //shortcuts_span.appendChild(today_link);
    //shortcuts_span.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u00A0|\u00A0'));
    shortcuts_span.appendChild(cal_link);
```

после чего надо будет почистить кэш статики (иначе js не перезагрузится)

> manage.py collectstatic --clear

Comment: ...и при любом обновлении Django все изменения слетят. Не надо так

Comment: @Sergey Tatarincev, спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Написать свой виджет, скопировать этот файл под другим именем, указать виджету что нужно использовать этот JS и все... Согласен с @andreymal, править файл из `django` в `site-packages` не стоит.

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант без правки js админки - прописать кастомный css для модели, который будет используваться в админке и спрятать весь текст в виджетах

admin.py

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        css = {
             'all': ('/static/css/admin-extras.css',)
        }
admin.site.register(Model,MyModelAdmin)
```

admin-extras.css

```
.datetimeshortcuts{
   font-size: 0;
}
```